# Unknown process shuts down computer when ending process tree

Tags: windows, process, windows-vista

***/I'm not sure if this is the correct place for this question/***

A few minutes ago, I discovered a strange process running in the background.

" **P3RTZCU17K.exe** " - I googled it with quotes and zero results were returned.

When I ended the process, Windows (Vista Home Premium) immediately displayed the blue screen physical memory dump page.

I've restarted the computer in Safe Mode (without networking) and am running CCleaner & Malwarebytes.

My question: Any idea what that process could be?!

***update**:
Malwarebytes has found several infected files, including a Backdoor bot.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be some form of malware based on you description and update. I suggest you get out your back ups and look at restoring your OS, unless you want to clean your PC but risk malware residual being left behind